# Iterate and change values of a column if a pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame and one of the columns is 'ip' in which each row is a ip address. I want to use the values and make a call to [project honeypot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/) and change the value of the column with the threat score. I'm using [this](https://github.com/gmr/httpbl) client to make the calls.

I tried with for loop and the [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) but i can't get it to do nothing :(. Does anyone have some suggestion or example?

`import httpbl
bl = httpbl.HttpBL('****')
df['ip'] = df.ip.apply(bl.query(df.ip.get_values, axis =1)`

a ... ip
1 ... 123.123.123.123
2 ... 123.24.2.1

and after the call get something like:

a ... ip
1 ... 17
2 ... 0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share your existing code, a sample of your input & desired output? This will help us understand your problem better. Also see [mcve].

Comment: Please, post what you've achieve so far.

Comment: I edited the post @jpp Abe

Comment: Have you tried `df['ip'] = df['ip'].apply(bl.query)` ? I'm not familiar with the library you are using so if you can include some link on how `bl.query` works, that might help.

Comment: https://github.com/gmr/httpbl @jpp

Comment: So how do you get it to work for a single IP address ?

Comment: Yes if i use like:
`response = bl.query('172.18.164.1')  `  
I get a json where one of the values is threat score